# CSS Transition - Show div smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Here's the idea:  A div on top which is hidden by default and will slide down, *pushing other content*, by the click of a button.  Another click will slide the div to be hidden again, raising the other content.

### HTML

```
<div id="topDiv" class="hidden">
    Some content<br>
    More very complex content
</div>
<button id="thebutton" onclick="toggle('topDiv');">Toggle the div</button>
<div id="bottomDiv">
    Some content<br>
    More content!<br>
    Even more content!<br>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.hidden {
    height: 0px;
}
div {
    height: 400px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
}
```

### Javascript

```
function toggle(someId) {
    var someElem = document.getElementById(someId);
    someElem.className = someElem.className == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden';
}
```

The issue here is that the content of the div that I want to be hidden is shown.  If I alter `div.hidden` to have `display: none;` or `visibility: hidden;` then I lose the "sliding" effect.

I would like to have a solution that does not use jQuery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` on the div.

Comment: As a side note: keep in mind that Webkit browsers don't support unprefixed transition, so add a -webkit-transition line as well.

Comment: Addendum: [recent Webkits support unprefixed `transition`](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions), but that doesn't include all Androids and iDevices yet - so keep prefixing for the time being.

Comment: Given that this answer was recently upvoted: `transition` no longer requires any prefixes on reasonably up to date browsers. I've stopped prefixing it in new sites a while back.